# How to show articles when age is equal to specific string?

Tags: android

so what I want to do is :
I have some articles in my database (I’m using room database) and I want to show them to user when the age is equal to a specific age (for example if he is 20 he will get article number 20 ) .
How can I do this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a DAO which will have some method like `getArticleForAge(age: Int)`. You will need to create a custom Query for that function which will take an input parameter and return the `Article` entity.

Example

**Kotlin**

```
@Dao
interface ArticleDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :age")
    fun getArticleForAge(age: Int): Article
}
```

**Java**

```
@Dao
interface ArticleDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :age")
    public Article getArticleForAge(int age);
}
```

Comment: I will try it and tell you

Comment: You can pass the age parameter to this function where you call it. So if you are calling it from some activity, you can get the user object first and pass the age of that user object to this method to retrieve the appropriate article.